# Histogram Matching implementation with java?

Tags: java, histogram, matching

I am coding histogram matching for 2 images. I cannot find matches between my 2 inverse-cdf.
Below are my code snippet. I calculate histogram for RGB space only for example.
HistogrammeRGB computes respectively histogram for each channel.
HistogrammeCumuleRGB computes the cdf for each channel.
InverseHistogrammeRGB computes the inverse-cdf for each channel. I use hashtable for storing it.

```
public static void HistogrammeRGB(Mat m,float[] R,float[] G,float[] B)
{
    byte[] col=new byte[3];
    for(int i=0;i<m.rows();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m.cols();j++)
        {                   
            m.get(i, j,col);
            R[byteColorCVtoIntJava(col[2])]+=1;
            G[byteColorCVtoIntJava(col[1])]+=1;
            B[byteColorCVtoIntJava(col[0])]+=1;             
        }
    }
    int N=m.rows()*m.cols();

    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        R[i]/=N;
        G[i]/=N;
        B[i]/=N;    
    }
}
public static void HistogrammeCumuleRGB(Mat m,float[] R,float[] G,float[] B,float[] RC,float[] GC,float[] BC,float N)
{

    float valueR=0;float valueG=0;float valueB=0;
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {

        valueR+=R[i];RC[i]=R[i]==0?0:valueR;
        valueG+=G[i];GC[i]=G[i]==0?0:valueG;
        valueB+=B[i];BC[i]=B[i]==0?0:valueB;

    }
}
public static void InverseHistogrammeRGB(float[] RC,float[] GC,float[] BC,Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulR,Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulG,Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulB )
{
    for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
    {               
        InvHistoCumulR.put(RC[i], i);
        InvHistoCumulG.put(GC[i], i);
        InvHistoCumulB.put(BC[i], i);           
    }
}
public static void MatchingHistogram(Mat imRef,Mat imTarget,Mat result)
{
    float[] RRef=new float[256];float[] RCRef=new float[256];Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulRRef=new Hashtable<>();
    float[] GRef=new float[256];float[] GCRef=new float[256];Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulGRef=new Hashtable<>();
    float[] BRef=new float[256];float[] BCRef=new float[256];Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulBRef=new Hashtable<>();
    float[] RTar=new float[256];float[] RCTar=new float[256];Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulRTar=new Hashtable<>();
    float[] GTar=new float[256];float[] GCTar=new float[256];Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulGTar=new Hashtable<>();
    float[] BTar=new float[256];float[] BCTar=new float[256];Hashtable<Float, Integer> InvHistoCumulBTar=new Hashtable<>();
    int N=imRef.cols()*imRef.rows();
    HistogrammeRGB(imRef, RRef, GRef, BRef);
    HistogrammeCumuleRGB(imRef, RRef, GRef, BRef,RCRef,GCRef,BCRef,N);
    InverseHistogrammeRGB(RCRef, GCRef, BCRef, InvHistoCumulRRef, InvHistoCumulGRef, InvHistoCumulBRef);
    HistogrammeRGB(imTarget, RTar, GTar, BTar);
    HistogrammeCumuleRGB(imTarget, RTar, GTar, BTar,RCTar,GCTar,BCTar,N);
    InverseHistogrammeRGB(RCTar, GCTar, BCTar, InvHistoCumulRTar, InvHistoCumulGTar, InvHistoCumulBTar);
    byte[] pixel=new byte[3];
    byte[] pixelTarget=new byte[3];
    // 

    for(int i=0;i<imRef.rows();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<imRef.cols();j++)
        {
            imRef.get(i, j,pixel);
            imTarget.get(i, j,pixelTarget);
            byte blue=pixel[0];byte green=pixel[1];byte red=pixel[2];
            /*int r=InvHistoCumulRTar.get(RCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(red)])==null?byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixelTarget[2]):InvHistoCumulRTar.get(RCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(red)]);
            int g=InvHistoCumulGTar.get(GCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(green)])==null?byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixelTarget[1]):InvHistoCumulGTar.get(GCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(green)]);
            int b=InvHistoCumulBTar.get(BCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(blue)])==null?byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixelTarget[0]):InvHistoCumulBTar.get(BCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(blue)]);*/
            float r=InvHistoCumulRTar.get(RCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(red)])==null?byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixel[2])*byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixelTarget[2])/255:InvHistoCumulRTar.get(RCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(red)]);
            float g=InvHistoCumulGTar.get(GCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(green)])==null?byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixel[1])*byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixelTarget[1])/255:InvHistoCumulGTar.get(GCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(green)]);
            float b=InvHistoCumulBTar.get(BCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(blue)])==null?byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixel[0])*byteColorCVtoIntJava(pixelTarget[0])/255:InvHistoCumulBTar.get(BCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(blue)]);
            System.out.println(InvHistoCumulRTar.get(RCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(red)])+" - "+InvHistoCumulGTar.get(GCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(green)])+" - "+InvHistoCumulBTar.get(BCRef[byteColorCVtoIntJava(blue)]));
            pixel[0]=(byte)b;
            pixel[1]=(byte)g;
            pixel[2]=(byte)r;
            result.put(i, j, new double[]{b,g,r});
        }
    }
}
public static int byteColorCVtoIntJava(byte b)
{       
    int i=(b+128)+128;      
    return b>=0?(int)b:i;
}
```